# C++ - A few quetions about my textbook's ASCII table

Tags: c++, char, ascii

In my c++ textbook, there is an "ASCII Table of Printable Characters."

I noticed a few odd things that I would appreciate some clarification on:

1. Why do the values start with 32? I tested out a simple program and it has the following lines of code: `char ch = 1; std::cout << ch << "\n";` of code and nothing printed out. So I am kind of curious as to why the values start at 32.
2. I noticed the last value, 127, was "Delete." What is this for, and what does it do?
3. I thought `char` can store 256 values, why is there only 127? (Please let me know if I have this wrong.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 0 - 31 are used, but are "unprintable" - things like Control-C.  Original ASCII didn't need beyond 127, use varies. Full table at: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table

Comment: I feel like this would be better answered by reading the wikipedia ASCII article.

Comment: Note that C++ is almost always used on ASCII systems. _Almost always_. Some GSM phones may use the SMS alphabet instead, and IBM systems (other than the PC) use EBCDIC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The **printable** characters start at 32. Below 32 there are non-printable characters (or *control characters*), such as BELL, TAB, NEWLINE etc.
2. DEL is a non-printable character that is equivalent to delete.
3. `char` can indeed store 256 values, but its signed-ness is implementation defined. If you need to store values from 0 to 255 then you need to explicitly specify `unsigned char`. Similarly from -128 to 127, have to specify `signed char`.

**EDIT**

The so called extended ASCII characters with codes >127 are not part of the ASCII standard. Their representation depends on the so called ["code page"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) chosen by the operating system. For example, MS-DOS used to use such extended ASCII characters for drawing directory trees, window borders etc. If you changed the code page, you could have also used to display non-English characters etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) between integers and characters plus other "control" "characters" like space, line feed and carriage return interpreted by display devices (possibly virtual). As such it is arbitrary, but they are organized by binary values.

1. 32 is a power of 2 and an alphabet starts there.
2. Delete is the signal from your keyboard delete key.
3. At the time the code was designed only 7 bits were standard. Not all bytes (parts words) were 8 bits.